# Error 500 en un servlet ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, java-ee, spring-tool-suite

Estoy empezando con j2ee y bueno empece con un servlet muy simple,pero siempre que trato de ejecutarlo me da un error 500,una excepción CLassNotFoundException de la clase del servlet LoginServlet en este caso y buscando en el proyecto no encuentro ningún fichero LoginServlet.class parece como si la clase LoginSevlet no se compilase.

index.php

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="login">
        <input type="text" name="nombre"></input>
        <input type="submit" value="Enviar"></input>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

LoginServlet.java

```
package com.prueba1;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class LoginServlet
 */
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public LoginServlet() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>LoginServlet</display-name>
    <description></description>
    <servlet-class>com.prueba1.LoginServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>LoginServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Este es el error,hace bastante que no uso eclipse pero se supone que al darle a Run as-->Run on server las ficheros java se compilan,ademas la opcion Build automatically está activada.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Error instanciando clase de servlet [com.prueba1.LoginServlet]
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
causa raíz

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.prueba1.LoginServlet
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` es que no se ha encontrado la clase dentro del *classpath*. La configuración parece correcta, añade la información de dónde está localizada la clase dentro de la webapp

Comment: @SJuan76 ,he ido a Properties->Java Build Path y estan prueba1/src/main/java, prueba1/src/main/resources y prueba1/src/test/java  el fichero .java esta en \prueba1\src\main\resources\com\prueba1(no veo una opcion para añadir mas directorios) pero el error sigue , Es aqui o debo cambiar algo en otro sitio?

Comment: El fichero java debe ir en prueba1/src/main/java/com/prueba1/ no en prueba1/src/main/resources

Answer (score 0):

Agrega el jar de servlet-api.jar a tu proyecto, debe estar en la ruta `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\lib` si usas tomcat(la ruta depende de tu instalación).

En eclipse clic derecho al proyecto->Build path->configure build path->Libraries->add external jars y agregas el jar anterior.Con eso debe funcionar.

**Actualizada:**

Si estas usando maven, agrega esta dependencia al pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: He añadido el servlet-api.jar y sigue dando el mismo error ,estoy usando sping tools suite ,en lugar de eclipse solo,por si sirve de ayuda.

Comment: y estas usando maven???

Comment: si ,el archetype webapp

Answer (score 0):

Yo tuve el mismo problema y la solución resultó ser añadir una carpeta java que no existía y meter dentro los .java. Por lo visto es una carpeta necesaria que debe colgar de src/main.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]